# Can I include a view using R.layout in java

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two xmls:

- main_layout.xml
- item_layout.xml

There is a `LinearLayout` in `main_layout` which has id `R.id.customContainer`.
How can I programatically `<include>` second layout (using somehow `R.layout.item_layout` ?) into my `customContainer`?

I have already a reference to `ViewGroup customContainer`, but `addView` method accepts `View` - and I don't know how to create having only xml layout file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, customContainer, false);
customContainer.addView(view);
```

Comment: It replaces everything I had in `customContainer`, can I append instead of replacing?